# Laravel 4, Composer, PSR-0 Autoloading Issues

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, psr-0

I'm experiencing a weird problem with a package I'm developing in the workbench.  It involves this little peice of my Composer file:

```
"psr-0": {
    "Vendor\\": "src/"
}
```

What I'm wanting to do is change the path like this:

```
"psr-0": {
    "Vendor\\": "src/models/"
}
```

Laravel has problems with this.  The classes get added to my application just fine, but all Laravel pathing to package resources get jacked up.

Things like this:

```
View::make('package::myview')
Config::get('package::myvars')
```

These do not work at all.  I get errors like this:

```
No hint path defined for [packge]
```

But if I remove the "models/" from the PSR-0 path then it all works fine.

So basically, it looks like Laravel insists that my Composer file have only "src/" in my PSR-0 paths.

This is a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you just need to add a models dir in your workbench besides using psr-0?

Comment: What your `ServiceProvider` looks like ? can you post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel presumes 2 levels down from the Provider file, but you can manually set the path to the `src/` when you register the package:

```
$this->package('vendor/package', null, __DIR__.'/../../../');
```